# БД со всеми городами

Tags: sql, база-данных

есть ли в открытом доступе БД с городами для ru или en? БД со странами я нашел, а с городами все сложно. Ну или на крайняк какие-нибудь интерфейсы гугл/яндекс?

Comment: Ну как бы в [ФИАС](http://fias.nalog.ru/Updates.aspx) есть не то что города - отдельные дома... мало?

Comment: жесть конечно, как все это распарсить непонятно... Да и там вроде как одни индификаторы и коды регионов, самих названий я чет там не нашел

Comment: *самих названий я чет там не нашел* Чем смотрел, спрашивается? Файл `AS_ADDROBJ_*.XML`. Города - `AOLEVEL="4"`.

Comment: полно сервисов геопозиции с городами и ипами. оттуда можно вынуть. например, https://lite.ip2location.com/database/ip-country-region-city

Answer (score 0):

Классификатор адресов России [КЛАДР](https://www.gnivc.ru/inf_provision/classifiers_reference/kladr/)

Comment: КЛАДР устарел на два потопа и официально выведен из эксплуатации.

Comment: Не знал, спасибо